# Will running hydraulic brake levers upside down affect performance

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I purchased a pair of tektro draco disc brakes recently. They arrived with the hydraulic lines setup moto style, with the longer line run for the left brake lever and the shorter run for the right brake lever.

I wanted to switch it to have left lever / front brake, right lever / rear brake.  So, I just swapped the levers to the opposite side, but now they point resivoir end down.  The only issue I have with this setup is that i have to loosen the levers and rotate them around the bar to bleed them with the reservoir facing up.

Will this cause any performance issues with braking?

Comment: Why not just switch the brake lines? The reservoir being at the top helps air not get into the important parts on most disc brake models, as any bubbles that occur find their way to the top with use where they hang out out of the way, in my opinion running them upside down is asking for issues.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I suspect "inspired by", but I do suspect the answers will be the same. Specifically "try it an see, it worked for me". There are a lot of design subtleties that could affect this, to the point where even the manufacturer may not know.

Comment: I would not trust hydraulic brakes with the reservoir upside-down, unless the manufacturer specifically permits that orientation.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm pretty much the opposite view, since the reservoir shouldn't have air in it and should be sealed, so it's more a "what side of the balloon has the hole" than "what if my feeder line is sucking air". But I am much more experimental than a lot of people.

Comment: I don't think its necessarily a dup, but @NateWengert's solution is the sensible one.

Comment: If you're right handed, the front brake should be under your right hand.  Consider trying it like this for a week and see how it feels.  You may be surprised.  If it doesn't feel better, you're no worse off and can still explore swapping sides.

Comment: @Criggie - All my bikes have front brake on the left. I think the side which the brake should be on varies depending on side of the road you ride on in your country, so that the back brake is operated with your non-signaling hand. This way you don't accidentally OTB yourself by grabbing too much front brake when signaling a turn across opposing traffic. See related question. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/why-is-the-front-brake-lever-on-the-right-if-you-drive-on-the-left-and-vice-ve

Comment: @NateWengert - I probably should do this eventually. I'm new to hydraulic brake setup and maintinance, so I'm still trying to figure out how to do things the right way. I'm assuming I can just unscrew the ends of the hydraulic cables from the levers and screw them on to the opposite levers and then re-bleed everything?

Comment: @Benzo yup you got it. That's what i would do, i much prefer the right brake to be the rear as well,may be an american thing. I believe sense your not actually shortening anything you shouldn't need any additional fittings either.

Comment: That was my point - you can try it "right hand front brake" for a bit without changing anything.  Might be less work than cutting tubing and bleeding fluids.   And if you don't like it, you're no worse off and can continue with trying to swap things around.   Just cos "this is the way it always was" isn't a good enough reason to keep doing it that way.

Comment: I'm so hardwired to expect the brakes to be setup the same, it could cause a dangerous situation for me if I set it up opposite of what I expect since this is on a mountain bike and I often do hard and fast braking while riding singletrack. It only takes one hard grab on the wrong brake lever to send me over the bars while going down a sketchy trail. 

Luckily though, I shouldn't have to cut the tubing if I swap the levers and I need to bleed my brakes again anyway, so it shouldn't be a whole lot of work on my part, just a couple bucks worth of new mineral oil.